# Google Map Marker not being replaced

Tags: google-maps-api-3, onclicklistener, markers

please excuse a noob at this. When a user clicks on a map, it should place a marker and open an info window - as per this example: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_click2add_infowindow.html
The code below almost works correctly, except that the mark is not replaced - a new one is added. Any ideas really, really gratefully received. Thank you.

```
<script>
    var map = null;
    var markersArray = [];

    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.0000, 0.0000);

        var settings = {
            zoom: 2,
            mapTypeControl:true,
            center: latlng,
            panControl:true,
            zoomControl:true,
            streetViewControl:false,
            overviewMapControl:false,
            rotateControl:true,
            scaleControl: true,
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            backgroundColor: 'white'
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), settings);

        function placeMarker(location) {
        var marker , i ;
        if ( marker ) {
                marker.setPosition(location);
            } else {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            icon:'http://www.desperatesailors.com/templates/Live/media/mapicons/info.png',
            map: map
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() +
                    '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng() +
                    '<br>Only the first four decimal places needed'
            });
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
        });
    }

    window.onload = initialize;
</script>
```

Comment: Mark answers if you are getting effective help. It makes the whole SO thing work when you close the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your placeMarker function creates a new (empty) marker variable in the local scope.

```
function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker , i ;
    if ( marker ) {
```

It will always create a new marker.  Change it to:

```
var marker = null;
function placeMarker(location) {
    if ( marker ) {
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I am so new at this, so completely lost. What do I need to do to fix that? By the way, it is meant to create a new marker and remove the old one.

Comment: One way would be to use the original code.  The other would be to remove the local definition of marker.

Comment: Also, FYI, your code either creates a marker (if one doesn't exist), or moves the existing marker (marker.setPosition(...))

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue. You are always delcaring marker in the placeMarker function so if( marker ) will always be false. Move the variable declaration out of that function:

```
<script>
    var marker;
    var map = null;
    var markersArray = [];

    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.0000, 0.0000);

        var settings = {
            zoom: 2,
            mapTypeControl:true,
            center: latlng,
            panControl:true,
            zoomControl:true,
            streetViewControl:false,
            overviewMapControl:false,
            rotateControl:true,
            scaleControl: true,
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            backgroundColor: 'white'
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), settings);

        function placeMarker(location) {
        var i ;
        if ( marker ) {
                marker.setPosition(location);
            } else {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            icon:'http://www.desperatesailors.com/templates/Live/media/mapicons/info.png',
            map: map
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() +
                    '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng() +
                    '<br>Only the first four decimal places needed'
            });
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
        });
    }

    window.onload = initialize;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, but that code doesn't work either! All I get is a blank screen?

Comment: Here's a working version online to refer to if you like: http://michaelreed.org/so/mapmarker.html